# i am trying camera led blink on phone call but is not well working

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-intent

I am trying to make the LED flash light to blink when the device receive an incoming call. my code in receive is work ..but flash light is not blink plz check the code and give me some suggestion why this code is not work...thanks in adv

```
 MainActivity


  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      }




   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); 
       return true;
    }

  }
`


  BroadcastReceiver
  `package com.example.flashringing;

  import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;

  import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.hardware.Camera;
    import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
   import android.widget.Toast;

 public class IncomingCall extends BroadcastReceiver {                                    

    private Camera camera;
    private boolean isFlashOn;
    private boolean hasFlash;
    Camera.Parameters params;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {                                          
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);                        
        String msg = "Ringing" + state;
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){                                   
     String incomingNumber  



  =intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);  
           // msg += ". Incoming number is " + incomingNumber;


            Toast.makeText(context, "Brodcaststart>>>>",    


  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.print("Brodcaststart>>>>");   

            // TODO This would be a good place to "Do something when the  

  phone rings" ;-)
            String myString = "0101010101";
            long blinkDelay = 50;
            getCamera();

          Toast.makeText(context, "cameraopen>>>>", 
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

            System.out.print("cameraopen>>>>");  

            for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
                if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
                    // params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                    turnOnFlash();
                } else {
                    // 


  params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    turnOffFlash();
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    private void turnOnFlash() {
        if (!isFlashOn) {
            if (camera == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }

            System.out.print("turnonflash>>>>");  

            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.startPreview();
            isFlashOn = true;


        }

    }

    private void getCamera() {
        if (camera == null) {
            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                params = camera.getParameters();

                System.out.print("cameraopen>>>>");  
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                 // Log.d(  Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", 


e.getLocalizedMessage()););



                System.out.println("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: 


  "+e.getLocalizedMessage());

            }
        }
    }
    private void turnOffFlash() {
        if (isFlashOn) {
            if (camera == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }


            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.release();
            isFlashOn = false;

        }
      }
    }`



   AndroidManifest.xml`<manifest      

  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.flashringing"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.flashringing.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.flashringing.IncomingCall"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

   </manifest>``
```